# JQuery for fetching ids of nodes in tree view structure to save data on the basis of ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, dom

Here m using angular to populate data in my view.. this is just a sample.. 
on clicking on the particular ageGroupCategory i need to add data into a form and then i want to save the entire data including the parent id of the nodes. help me with the JQuery code to fetch the Parent node ids.. as i m using ng-repeat directive of angular i cant get parent ids at child node..
help me with the suggestions..

```
<div> 
    <ul>
        <li id="{{sport._id}}" ng-repeat="sport in sports">
            <a>{{sport.sportsName}}</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="sub_{{subSport._id}}" ng-repeat="subSport in sport.subSports"> 
                    <a>{{subSport.subSportsName}}</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="age_{{ageGrp._id}}" ng-repeat="ageGrp in subSport.ageGroup">
                            <a>{{ageGrp.ageGroupName}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what your use case is?  It is uncommon in an [tag:angular] project to have to interact directly with the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('li a').on('click', function(){

    var id = $(this).parent().id;
    // get the rest of your data and do some cool stuff
  });

});
```

Comment: yes.. u r in right way.. but tree structure is dynamic and want parent ids to save the data.. i have implement some jquery similar as yours.. its working a bit..